# R BayesVarSel on Ubuntu installation

Tags: r, ubuntu, g++, gnu, gsl

I'm trying to install the `BayesVarSel` package on a `ubuntu` 12 box on `AWS EC2`.  It works fine on my windows 7 machine (`R 2.15.1`).

I've attached a screenshot of the error message.  It appears to be an issue with the GNU GSL library.  I couldn't find a quick way to install GSL (ie sudo apt-get GSL, etc.) so I wanted to see if others have had a similar issue.  I'm open to other packages with similar functionality.[image]

EDIT:
A couple other things I've tried without luck :
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to recreate the error with Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS (desktop) running in VirtualBox.
As @Dirk Eddelbuettel suggested, `sudo apt-cache search libgsl` produced a useful list of packages. It's not clear why that didn't work on your machine.

I installed libgsl with:

```
sudo apt-get install libgsl0ldbl
sudo apt-get install libgsl0-dev
```

Now `BayesVarSel` compiles and loads without error.

Comment: You just need one `apt-get` call of the `-dev` package, it will pull the library in for you.  And generally speaking you can submit multiple packages to `apt-get` all at once.

Answer (score 2):

Do

```
 apt-cache search libgsl
```

and everything should be a little clearer.  Those packages have existed longer than either Ubuntu or Amazon EC2 so it really should not take superhuman effort to find them.

And if `apt-cache search libgsl` is too difficult, try [packages.ubuntu.com](http://packages.ubuntu.com)
where you can search for the package containing the file in your error message (eg `/usr/include/gsl/gsl_vector.h`) and "Yes, Veronica" you can search for substrings too.

Comment: I tried your suggestions and nothing seemed to happen.  I posted screenshots above.  Sorry if this is a newbie question, but I'm not very familiar with the plumbing in linux.  Thanks for your suggestions.

Comment: search issue was my fault.  Forgot to run 'sudo apt-get update'.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

On Fedora the required package can be installed with `dnf install gsl-devel`.